# Do Marsupials have a standard classification system for their blood groups?

Tags: hematology, marsupials

I've seen a limited amount of animal blood groups listed...like dogs, cats, horses, etc. But what blood types do marsupials have?

To clarify, what I want to know is if the species has a classification system similar to the ABO blood group? For example: Blood Type A, Blood Type B, etc.
Or in the case of Dogs, the classification system is labeled as: Dea 1.1, Dea 1.2, etc.

Comment: I'm interested in this myself, as we are developing a school program on genetics and would like to include this info if it is available. A quick Google search comes up with the Wikipedia page that includes dogs, cats, horses etc. that you mentioned, plus a couple of research papers on the grey opossum and a 1960 article on koalas. I suspect that this won't change unless a large number of people start to keep marsupials as domestic pets, and the inevitable large number of injuries or operations requiring blood transfusions by the local vet.